# Use substring function or a regular expression

Tags: c#, string

I want to extract an ID from a string which has the form "somethinguseless_XXXXX ".
XXXXX is the ID I need. The string always has the same length and the format won't change over time.

I found 2 solutions to extract the ID => `oldAttribute.substring(17,22)` or `Regex.Match(oldAttribute,@"_([0-9]{5})").Groups[1].value`.

Which one do you think is better than the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the length is consistent, `Substring()` will work just as well and likely perform better. A quick test over a few million iterations would probably verify that assumption.

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'd got for the option 3, split the string based on the underscore.

```
var id = "somethinguseless_XXXXXX".Split('_')[1];
```

You'll want to do some better testing to make sure the array is the length you want but this is the approach I'd likely take.

I know you've said that the string will always be the same length and won't change over time, but my experience tells me that things can always change and often aren't always the same.

Comment: That assumes that Somethinguseless may not contain underscores :)

Comment: aha, well spotted :) I think I might still take this approach but with a bit more testing involved. Glad you pointed this out tho!

Comment: Furthermore, the string is "somethinguseless_XXXXXX ", there's a space at the end so it won't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can just trim the sting first in that case. "somethinguseless_XXXXX ".Trim().Split('_');

Comment: What about `var id = "somethinguseless_XXXXXX ".Split('_').Last().Trim();` ? Substring() will probably still be faster, this solution is just a bit more adaptive to changes in input.

Comment: To use the `String.SubString()` function seems a little more efficient than `String.Trim().Split()`, am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

using `Regex` is more flixable than `SubString` but I think the performance of `SubString` is greater.

Answer (score 0):

substring is the better option - when you know the location of the ID with in the string.

Answer (score 0):

its my suggestion , if the format is same and if "somethinguseless" doesn't contain _ you can use string.split();

Answer (score 0):

```
int p=5; //length of the substring    
string id = oldAttribute.substring(oldAttribute.Length-p, p)
```

Answer (score -1):

Go for the second one.

Regex.Match(oldAttribute,@"_([0-9]{5})").Groups[1].value

This will even work in case ur string length before underscore gets changed anyhow.